# Search a column for highest value, return matching cell reference in column A

Tags: excel, if-statement, max

In this example, the goal is to use =MAX and an IF formula to search Column C for the highest numerical value, and then return the contents of a cell in Column A in the same row as the highest numerical value in Column C in the cell marked with an ?. In this case, cell C2 would have the highest numerical value, so 'DEF' would be displayed in place of the ?.

Comment: In which language is this question? java? sql? if is sql what engine? mySql? postgres?

Comment: Be polite, attempting to edit the question to appear more legible.

Comment: This is a Microsoft Excel question, thank you for clarifying.

Comment: Have you just copied and pasted the homework question? That's....pretty lazy...

Comment: Very insightful commentary, thank you, RB. A simple question, feel free to not answer it if you prefer.

Comment: Well, to avoid comments like the one that @RB. did, you should check this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Magra Ok, for a more insightful comment - use [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) - that is an Excel function designed to lookup a cell in the same row, but a different column in a table of data, which sounds like your question.

Comment: @RB While I agree that `VLOOKUP` would normally be the goto for something like this, it only works when the returned information is to the right of the lookup column.  In this case, the lookup column is C and the information to return is in column A.  `INDEX/MATCH` is better suited in this instance.  Either way though, the original poster has shown no effort to solve the problem and thus doesn't warrant us providing any help.

Comment: Ideally, StackOverflow questions take a pretty standard form. 1) clearly describe the problem that you're trying to solve, you should assume the people reading the question only know about the tools available to solve the problem, not the problem itself; 2) describe what you've tried so far, ideally with an actual snippet of code; 3) describe what the results of your attempts thus far have been and why you still feel like the problem isn't solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appreciate the responses, my apologies for the unclear question. I've found a solution to this issue, should anyone encounter a similar situation.

The goal was to use a formula in a column to check the numerical values in that column for the highest number, and then return the text contained in column A within the same row as the cell with the highest value.

I've achieved this using the following two formulas:

=ADDRESS(MATCH(MAX(O3:O27),O:O,0),1,4)
('O3:O27' is the array you would search to find the highest number. In this scenario, I placed this formula out of the way in Cell O200).

This formula will return the Cell in Column A that is in the same row as the cell with the highest number.

I then added an additional formula to then display the text contained within the cell in Column A in the same row as the cell with the highest number, see below:

=INDIRECT(O200)
(O200 being the cell we entered the first formula in).

The cell we enter the =INDIRECT(O200) formula in will then display the contents of the cell in column A that is in the same row as the cell with the highest value.

Thank you for your time, I hope this helps.